# Best way to check database constantly

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, batch-processing

I was assigned to a spring boot project that needs to check the DB constantly in order to detect changes and get some data.
It uses a while loop to get the information **when the application starts**:

```
@Async("SomeExecutor")
public void syncData() throws InterruptedException {
  while (true) {
    var values = someRepository.findAll()
    doSomethingWithValues(values);
  }
}
```

Is there some tool, library or better practise to achive this? Maybe using @Scheduler?

Comment: Do you really need to monitor the database itself? If your application is the only one updating the table, you could create some kind of event-based system. Would that help for your use case?

Comment: Hi @g00glen00b thanks for your reply. We don´t have this option yet but we´ll see. I get your point.